# Comparing 2 variables typed MvcHtmlString is always false

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, razor

i want compare 2 variable (typed mvcHtmlString) but the response is always false...

```
@{ //Load the good css file

    if (ViewBag.BrowserName == MvcHtmlString.Create("ie"))
    {
        if (ViewBag.BrowserVersion > 9)
        {
            @Styles.Render("~/Content/ie10-css")
        }
        else
        {
            @Styles.Render("~/Content/ie7-css")
        }
    }
    else if (ViewBag.BrowserName == MvcHtmlString.Create("safari")) //and ipad
    {
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/safari/css")
    }
    else  //if (ViewBag.BrowserName == "firefox" || ViewBag.BrowserName == "chrome")
    {
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/default/css")
    }

}
```

My console show :

```
MvcHtmlString.Create("safari")                 -> {safari}
ViewBag.BrowserName                            -> {safari}
ViewBag.BrowserName == MvcHtmlString("safari") -> false
```

I ask why does it false ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public String GetBrowserName()
{
    ViewBag.logged = false;
    return (Request.Browser.Browser.ToLowerInvariant());
}
```

So, the Html.Action returns an MvcHtmlString (i don't know why) but is possible to force it to be a string directly in the cshtml page :

```
@if (ViewBag.BrowserName == null)
{
    ViewBag.BrowserName = Html.Action("GetBrowserName", "Services").ToString();
}
```

now compare the 2 string :

```
if (ViewBag.BrowserName == "safari")
```

Answer (score 1):

`MvcHtmlString.Create` does not create a string instance. The output is the same because it returns the  string you used in `ToString()` implementation. Since MvcHtmlString doesn't overload `==` operator, they can never be equal.

You can use regular strings for comparison:

```
if (ViewBag.BrowserName == "ie")
{ ... }
```

Comment: @E.H Then call ToString() on mvcHtmlString first: ViewBag.BrowserName.ToString() == "ie"